# An unexpected augmented assignment discount += item.total() * .1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am following "Fluent Python" to learn Function and Design Pattern:

In chapter 6 [example-code/strategy.py](https://github.com/fluentpython/example-code/blob/master/06-dp-1class-func/strategy.py)

```
def bulk_item_promo(order):
    """10% discount for each LineItem with 20 or more units"""
    discount = 0
    for item in order.cart:
        if item.quantity >= 20:
            discount += item.total() * .1 #augmented += ?
    return discount
```

I am very confused about:

```
discount += item.total() * .1
```

I assume it overhead complicated, because it's just

```
 discount = item.total() * .1
```

However, the author prefer to state it like

```
discount = 0*1 + 0*2 + 0*3 + item.total() * .1
```

to increase it complexity artificially.

What's the key points I missed? could you please provide any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code `discount += item.total() * .1` is equivalent to:

```
discount = discount + (item.total() * 0.1)
```

I've added the parentheses for clarity, but they are not necessary as multiplication has precedence over addition.

Your function calculates an **absolute** discount by aggregating discounts for all items with quantity greater than 20. The discount equates to 10% of the undiscounted cost of in-scope items.

The same function can also be written with `sum` and a generator expression:

```
def bulk_item_promo(order):
    """10% discount for each LineItem with 20 or more units"""
    return sum(item.total() * 0.1 for item in order.cart if item.quantity >= 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are 3 items in the order. Call them a, b, and c. Say that each one had more than 20 units. Say that `a.total() == b.total() == c.total() == 100`. In the case of:

```
discount = item.total() * .1
```

`discount` will be `10`. So you would get `10` off the entire `300`. But that isn't really what you want, you want `10` off of each `a.total()`, `b.total()` and `c.total()`, so you want `30`. This why you use `+=` instead as it aggregates over each (qualified) item.

Answer (score 1):

Every item in the basket can have a discount. To calculate the total discount, you need to add up the individual discounts for all items that have an discount, and that is what the code does. Calling the variable "total_discount" instead of "discount" might have been better.

```
left += right
```

means: Calculate the value "right", then add it to the variable left. discount_total += (formula for item discount) means calculate the item discount according to the formula, and add it to the discount_total. In your case

```
discount_total += item.total() * 0.1
```

means: Calculate the discount for this item by calculating its total and multiplying by 0.1 (which is the same as taking ten percent). Then add the discount for this item to the discount total.